# Explanation...is this in BCNF in respect of F

Tags: database, database-design, bcnf

Trying to learn about BCNF, but having a little bit of trouble understanding the functional dependency part of it.

Trying to get a database design SMS(SSN, sName, sMajor, sAddress) for a student management system (SMS) into BCNF. The functional dependency set is F={SSN->sAddress}

How do I move from here to get this into BCNF. I was thinking I would need something like:

Student(SSN, sAddress)
Info(sAddress, sName, sMajor)

Is that anything close to being correct?

Comment: BCNF means every determinant is a superkey. To be sure you have satisfied BCNF you therefore need to determine keys for your Student and Info relations. Given SSN->sAddress we can say that {SSN} is the key of student. In the absence of any other FD we can only conclude that {SSN,sName,sMajor} is the key of Info. Does that help?

Comment: Your initial sentence is a little vague.  Do you mean that you have trouble with the concept of functional dependency?  Or do you understand the concept pretty well as it applies to 1NF, 2NF, and 3NF, but not as it applies to BCNF?